# Trying to Inherit web Export in odoo 11

Tags: python, controller, odoo, odoo-11

I'm having trouble inheriting the CSVExport class in web.controller.main.

I want to apply [this](https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/how-to-export-date-time-as-per-my-timezone-in-odoo-11-154894) in my module but I have no idea how to properly inherit the CSVExport class.

here's my code so far.

```
# main.py
import io
from odoo import http
from odoo.http import request
from odoo.tools import pycompat
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from odoo.addons.web.controllers.main import CSVExport,ExcelExport
import werkzeug.utils
from dateutil.parser import parse
import pytz

class CSVExportInherit(CSVExport):

    def check_date(self, value):
        try:
            parse_data = parse(value)
            return parse_data
        except Exception as e:
            return False

    def from_data(self, fields, rows):
        fp = io.BytesIO()
        writer = pycompat.csv_writer(fp, quoting=1)
        writer.writerow(fields)
        for data in rows:
            row = []
            for d in data:
                if isinstance(d, pycompat.string_types) and d.startswith(('=', '-', '+')):
                    d = "'" + d
                if type(d) is str:
                    parse_data = self.check_date(d)
                    if parse_data:
                        if len(d) > 10:
                            tz = pytz.timezone(request._context.get('tz'))
                            # d = (pytz.utc.localize(datetime.datetime.strptime(d,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')).astimezone(tz)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
                            d = datetime.strptime(d,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') + timedelta(hours=8)

                row.append(pycompat.to_text(d))
            writer.writerow(row)
         return fp.getvalue()
```

my controllers init file `from . import main` and in my manifest I've added the `web` in `depends:` and I also imported the controllers in my `__init__.py`.

the error that I got is this.

```
Uncaught Error: QWeb2: Template 'Dialog' not found
```

when clicking the export button in list view.

I've also tried pasting my code to the main code on web module(instead of inherit), and it works fine, so I don't think there's a problem in the function.

A reference to a guide on how to inherit a web controller will be great help, cause all the tutorial that I saw when I search is all about how to inherit website_sale.

Comment: From the [Web Controllers](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/11.0/reference/http.html) reference: To override a controller, [inherit](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#tut-inheritance) from its class and override relevant methods, re-exposing them if necessary. ``Your code should work (tested)``

Comment: That's really weird, after my 3rd try new database it is working now